# Routing based on geolocation in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am trying to define my routing part based on the geolocation of the user.

**Context**: I have a store of products and I want to promo some products based on the region of the user by redirecting the user to the corresponding path.

**Example**:

- No detection: *store/products/*
- Bordeaux: *store/bordeaux/products/*
- Paris: *store/paris/products/*
- Product details: this is the confusing part, currently without geolocation part, I am using *store/products/:id* but now I should add the geolocation in product details page or not because basically, it is still the same product, just have some category field for a region

**Problem**: Before having this task, I have a category list with cause some conflict with this current task because category and geolocation is at the same place in the route

**Example**:

- Category A: *store/categorya/* will show all the products inside this category A

The current path setup

```
{
    path: 'store',
    component: StoreAppComponent,
    children: [
        { path: 'products/:id/', component: ProductComponent, outlet: 'store' },
        { path: 'products/', component: ProductsComponent, outlet: 'store' },
        { path: ':category', component: StoreComponent, outlet: 'store' },
        { path: '', component: StoreComponent, outlet: 'store' }
    ]
}
```

So how can I define the new route that can combine also category, geolocation with Angular 4, can you suggest the approach?

Comment: How would you like to show region specific products falling to a specific category? `store/region/category/products` or `store/category/region/products` ??

Comment: it is a very good question, I think the region is more general than category, but I am not very sure :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all this code block might have some errors so please test them before using.

The  idea that is being used here is to use a common child route object to address 3 scenarios -

default route (default region and category) `/store/*`

region specific route (category as default) `/store/:region/*`

region and category specific route `/store/:region/:category/*`

> EDIT : The important thing here is `:route wild card`.  It has to be registered in the end to make sure it will not override  any of the hard coded routes.

The implementation could be like this -

```
//Reusable Products Route
export const Productroutes: Route = {
    path: 'products',
    redirectTo: "products/list",
    children: [
        {
            path: "list",
            component: ProductListComponent,
        },
        {
            path: ":id",
            component: ProductComponent,
        }
    ]
}

export const routes: Route = {
    path: 'store',
    component: StoreAppComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: "",
            redirectTo: "sotre/products",
            //products CRUD will follow store/* routes without region and category default
            children: [Productroutes]
        },
        {
            path: ":region",
            redirectTo: "sotre/:region/products",
            //products CRUD will follow store/* routes with a region and default category route
            children: [
                Productroutes,
                {
                    path: ":category",
                    //products CRUD will follow store/* routes with a region and a category route.
                    redirectTo: "sotre/:region/:category/products",
                    children: [Productroutes]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Let me know if your requirement is different :)

Comment: Many thanks, your solution just aligned very well with my teamate suggestion :) We will remove the first category part, and place it after the region. The approach would be `store/:region/category/:categoryName` the product part, I am thinking about it but I think we will leave it separate with other route so it will display like this `store/products/:id`

Comment: That is even better! Just make sure you are using the wild card routes at the right place. That might give a headache later! :)